# Client side validation in Angular form for empty fields

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular14

I have created a login page with `form` tag, I want client side validation when user click Submit button, but nothing happens, `Checkform` method is not getting fired.
This is my code

```
 <div>
    <form class="login">
      <p class="title">Log in</p>
      <input type="text" class="form-control id="username" id="txtUsername" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide Username
      </div>
      <input  class="form-control type="text" id="email" id="txtPass" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide Password
      </div>
      <br>            
      <button type="button" onclick="Checkform()">
        <span class="state">Log in</span>
      </button>
    </form>
 </div>
```

I have added `bootstrap` classes for validation and also a method in `.ts` file which should fire when I click on submit button

```
 <div class="invalid-feedback">
     Please provide Username
 </div>

 <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Please provide Password
 </div>
```

```
  Checkform(){
    var form = document.getElementsByClassName('login')[0] as HTMLFormElement;
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      
    }
    form.classList.add('was-validated');
  }
```

How can I make client side validation for empty fields and fire a method when user click on Submit button ?

Comment: Any reason not to use angular forms here? You'll get this functionality for free https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client side validation I have fixed using `Reactive forms`. Its easy to develop

First add `ReactiveFormsModule` in `imports` section in the `app.modules.ts` file. In your `component.ts` file write below code

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm :FormGroup;
  submitted=false;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
    this.initializeForm();
  }

  initializeForm()
  {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      userName: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    }); 
  }

  UserLogin()
  {
    this.submitted = true;
    if(this.loginForm.invalid)
    {
      return
    }
  }
}
```

This is how you can design `component.html` file

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="UserLogin()">

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' :submitted && loginForm.controls['userName'].errors}"
       formControlName="userName" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control mt-2" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' :submitted && loginForm.controls['email'].errors}" 
      formControlName="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div> 
    
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
       <span class="state">Log in</span>
    </button>
    
</form>
```

Inside `initializeForm()` we have `userName` and `email`, these names should be the `formControlName` in `.html` file. You can add as many as fields you need. This is how login page looks like

[image]

If you want detailed information [visit this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ariLHGm-u3E)

Answer (score 0):

also, it's a good thing to disable the login or submit button if the form is not valid

```
<button type="submit"  [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
       Submit
</button>
```